# Type definition for a jagged array of type T and its array prototype extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a Typescript definition file for a JavaScript function I've attached to `Array.prototype`.

#### Array.js

```js
/**
 * Flattens the array recursively.
 *
 * @example
 * [1, [2, 3]].flat() // => [1, 2, 3]
 *
 * @example
 * [[1, [2, 3], [4, [5]]], 6].flat() // => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 */
Array.prototype.flat = function () {
    return this.reduce((arr, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? arr.concat(val.flat()) : arr.concat(val), []);
}
```

`flat()` works on an `Array<T|S>` where `S` is `Array<T|S>` and returns `Array<T>`.  That is, it has a recursive definition, and all arrays fit the definition, as `[1, 2, 3].flat()` will simply return a copy of the original array.

I'm new to TypeScript, but my understanding is that in order to get the benefits of a TypeScript definition file (namely IntelliSense), the method definition must be within `interface Array<T>`.  If this is the case, is there a way to place a constraint on `T` for a specialized version of `Array<T>`?

If not, how can I define an interface that will be picked up for every array AND will recognize when the array fits the recursive definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but it does get us most of the way. Here it is [in the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20type%20JaggedArrayItem%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20%7C%20JaggedArray%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20JaggedArray%3CT%3E%20extends%20Array%3CJaggedArrayItem%3CT%3E%3E%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20FlatArray%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%20extends%20JaggedArrayItem%3Cinfer%20U%3E%20%3F%20U%5B%5D%20%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20Array%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20flat(this%3A%20JaggedArray%3CT%3E)%3A%20FlatArray%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Array.prototype.flat%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.reduce(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(arr%2C%20val)%20%3D%3E%20Array.isArray(val)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3F%20arr.concat(val.flat())%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20arr.concat(val)%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Test%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20myRecursiveArray%3A%20JaggedArray%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%2010%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B9%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B8%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B7%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20flattened%3A%20number%5B%5D%20%3D%20myRecursiveArray.flat()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20TODO%20surface%20an%20error%20for%20union%20type%20array%20items.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20flattenedToo%3A%20(string%20%7C%20number)%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%20'two'%5D.flat()%3B).

```
type JaggedArrayItem<T> = T | JaggedArray<T>;

interface JaggedArray<T> extends Array<JaggedArrayItem<T>> { }

type FlatArray<T> = T extends JaggedArrayItem<infer U> ? U[] : T;

interface Array<T> {
  flat(this: JaggedArray<T>): FlatArray<T>;
}

Array.prototype.flat = function () {
  return this.reduce(
    (arr, val) => Array.isArray(val)
      ? arr.concat(val.flat())
      : arr.concat(val),
    []);
};

// Test

const myRecursiveArray: JaggedArray<number> = [
  10,
  [9],
  [
    [8],
    [
      [7],
    ]
  ],
];

const flattened: number[] = myRecursiveArray.flat();    
const flattenedToo: (string | number)[] = [1, 'two'].flat();
```

See also

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540
- https://github.com/shaunluttin/typescript-jagged-array-type-and-prototype

Comment: Is there a reason we need `FlatArray<T>`?  Can't `flat()`'s signature simply be `flat(this: JaggedArray<T>): Array<T>;`?  I'm also unsure of why we need to surface an error for union types. `[ 1, 'foo' ].flat()` should work, no?

Comment: @dfoverdx Good point about the TODO item for surfacing an error. I put that in there because I though that the original question wanted to avoid union types... I think I was mistaken about that, so I deleted that TODO item.

Comment: @dfoverdx If we return `Array<T>` instead of `FlatArray<T>`, then resultant type will not be a `T[]`. For instance, the `number[]` example would return this error at compile time: `Type 'JaggedArrayItem<number>[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'. Type 'JaggedArrayItem<number>' is not assignable to type 'number'. Type 'JaggedArray<number>' is not assignable to type 'number'.`